# When scrolling to end of an element don't scroll the parent element

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, scroll, safari, element

Imagine you have nested elements on a webpage like one textfield inside a parent-div-element. The content of the textfield overflows the textfield dimensions. The textfield itself and several different elements are inside a parent-div. All those elements are overflowing the parent-div's dimensions, too.

Now if you will focus the textfield and scroll up or down, the content will scroll to the bottom or top of it's content. But: After the bottom or to is reached, the parent div will scroll to it's bottom or top.
[image: scroll behaviour description]

This is an unwanted behaviour and I wonder if there is a way, a shortcut, a setting or extension to prevent the browser / OS from doing that.

The wanted behaviour is: I scroll to the bottom of a textfield and only if the focus changes or at least the mouse cursor leaves the textfield, the parent element shall scroll down.

This occurs in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OS X High Sierra 10.13.2. In Chrome there is a seamless scrolling, Firefox and Safari will prevent the parent from scrolling unless you initiate scrolling again. On Windows 10 and Firefox it is even more delayed, but still occuring - which makes it even harder to control. On Windows 10 and Edge it's seamless, too.